# Проверить правильность кода функций работы со строками

Tags: c++, строки

Я написал 3 функции: удаления значения, вставка в конец и вставка по индексу. Проверьте, правильно ли я сделал . Если не правильно подскажите где  ошибки

```
void Append(String* string1, const String* string2)
{
    if (string1->capacity > string1->length + string2->length + 1)
    {
        string1->capacity = string1->length + string2->length;
        string1->str = (char*)realloc(string1->str, string1->capacity * sizeof(char));
    }
    for (unsigned index = 0; index < string2->length; ++index)
        string1->str[string1->length + index] = string2->str[index];
    string1->str[string1->length + string2->length] = '\0';
    string1->length = string1->length + string2->length;
}

void Insert(String* string, unsigned index, char ch)
{
    string->str = (char*)realloc(string->str, string->capacity * sizeof(char));
    for (unsigned current = string->length; current > index; --current)
        string->str[current] = string->str[current - 1];
    string->str[string->length + 1] = '\0';
    ++string->length;
    Set(string, index, ch);
}

void Remove(String* string, unsigned index)
{
    char* str = strcpy(&string->str[index - 1], &string->str[index]);
    --string->length;
}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/

Comment: За такой код в реальном продукте расстреливают на месте. А для проверки кода пишут юнит-тесты.

Comment: у меня зацикливания при удалении . Где бага. А то я не могу понять(

Comment: Парни, Я не правильно написал.Я тестил свои программы. Но может  быть где то баги есть. Подскажите если увидете

Answer (score 1):

Все ваши функции некорректны.

В данной функции

```
void Append(String* string1, const String* string2)
{
    if (string1->capacity > string1->length + string2->length + 1)
    {
        string1->capacity = string1->length + string2->length;
        string1->str = (char*)realloc(string1->str, string1->capacity * sizeof(char));
    }
    for (unsigned index = 0; index < string2->length; ++index)
        string1->str[string1->length + index] = string2->str[index];
    string1->str[string1->length + string2->length] = '\0';
    string1->length = string1->length + string2->length;
}
```

если выполняется условие

```
string1->capacity > string1->length + string2->length + 1
```

то не надо перераспределять память для `string1`, не так ли?

Вы же перераспределяете память.

Более того вы выделяете память размером

```
string1->capacity = string1->length + string2->length;
```

которого недостаточно, чтобы после конкатенации двух строк дописать нулевой символ.

Кроме того для выделения памяти в целях сохранения корректного состояния объекта в случае, если память не будет выделена, следует использовать промежуточную временную переменную для указателя на новую выделенную память.

В этой функции

```
void Insert(String* string, unsigned index, char ch)
{
    string->str = (char*)realloc(string->str, string->capacity * sizeof(char));
    for (unsigned current = string->length; current > index; --current)
        string->str[current] = string->str[current - 1];
    string->str[string->length + 1] = '\0';
    ++string->length;
    Set(string, index, ch);
}
```

Вы вообще не проверяете `capacity`, а зачем-то перераспределяете память того же самого размера

```
    string->str = (char*)realloc(string->str, string->capacity * sizeof(char));
```

Поэтому функция имеет неопределенное поведение.

В этой функции

```
void Remove(String* string, unsigned index)
{
    char* str = strcpy(&string->str[index - 1], &string->str[index]);
    --string->length;
}
```

во-первых, вы не можете использовать выражение `&string->str[index - 1]`, если индексация идет, начиная с 0. И использование функции `strcpy` для перекрывающихся участков копирования влечет за собой неопределенное поведение.

Также всем функциям по аналогии со стандартными строковыми функциями следует возвращать  указатели на сами строки, чтобы можно было функции объединять в цепочки вызовов функций.

Comment: я 1  раз на сайте, а Вы уже набросились на меня, не правильно оформил. Ну извините... . Влад спасибо за показ моих ошибок. А всем остальным мир Вам.

Comment: @vova_makr Не за что. :)